# Cannot open designer of a form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, designer

I am currently working on a project using MS VS 2017.

I was able to open the designer and open the forms before. Now, I'm trying to open the same file but all forms' designers cannot be opened. But the project runs smoothly and I can edit the code.

I tried what others have suggested, like cleaning and building the solution, and deleting the obj subfolder, however none of these worked for me. What should I do?

This is what I get every time I try to open the designer:

```
The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed. 

at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

[image]

This is the code of the form I am trying to open:

```
Public Class frmLogin

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub

    Private Sub lblExit_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblExit.Click
        If (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to Exit?", "Exit from the system", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information)) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
        frmDashboard.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Have you custom controls inside your forms that you cannot be able to open?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Post the full code of the formX.vb that you're trying to open

Comment: Also (or better) the full code of the formX.Designer.vb

Comment: Is it possible you have any dialog inheritance there and changed the parent dialog to an abstract one?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. what I really meant was I badly need an immediate answer 'cozI can't continue working on it. Anw, thank you for editing my post. Em new to this actually. :)

Comment: I'm sorry if I don't understand what you mean with custom controls? @G3nt_M3caj

Comment: Uhm, I'm using user controls.

Comment: @GayflorDeGuzman, Custom Controls are controls you had made by your self (or third parties) then implemented in your project.

Comment: If you have Coustom Controls and if you those Controls, you had build in other projects, try rebuild those projects and re-import dll’s which Controls are in.

Answer (score 0):

The file you need to look at is frmLogin.Designer.vb in your project directory. You can see it by right-clicking (in Visual Studio), for instance "btnLogin" in the code that you posted above, then "Go To Implementation". Or just use File Explorer and open the file with NotePad to see inside.

This is where the design for your form is stored. The file contains auto-generated code and data for your form, and seems to be corrupted somehow, maybe it was accidentally edited.

I have no idea what frmLogin actually looks like, but here is a frmLogin.Designer.vb I just created using the names in your code;

I suggest you compare the contents of your file with the example below which should lead to the source of your problem:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>
Partial Class frmLogin
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()>
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.btnCancel = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.btnLogin = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.lblExit = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'btnCancel
    '
    Me.btnCancel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(310, 130)
    Me.btnCancel.Name = "btnCancel"
    Me.btnCancel.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(107, 43)
    Me.btnCancel.TabIndex = 0
    Me.btnCancel.Text = "Cancel"
    Me.btnCancel.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'btnLogin
    '
    Me.btnLogin.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(310, 192)
    Me.btnLogin.Name = "btnLogin"
    Me.btnLogin.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(107, 48)
    Me.btnLogin.TabIndex = 1
    Me.btnLogin.Text = "Log in"
    Me.btnLogin.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'lblExit
    '
    Me.lblExit.AutoSize = True
    Me.lblExit.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(233, 130)
    Me.lblExit.Name = "lblExit"
    Me.lblExit.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(24, 13)
    Me.lblExit.TabIndex = 2
    Me.lblExit.Text = "Exit"
    '
    'frmLogin
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(800, 450)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblExit)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnLogin)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnCancel)
    Me.Name = "frmLogin"
    Me.Text = "frmLogin"
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.PerformLayout()

End Sub

Friend WithEvents btnCancel As Button
Friend WithEvents btnLogin As Button
Friend WithEvents lblExit As Label
End Class
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where the project would build and run but the Windows Forms designer refused to display any forms or controls.

I had to delete the ProjectAssemblies directory and reopen the project and then it worked fine.
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio*16.0_72ecbfa4*\ProjectAssemblies